# Way around deploying prerequisites for Winform code

Tags: winforms, deployment, windows-installer, installation

Currently I have a 60MB assembly which needs a 100 MB of prerequisites to be installed. For example Visual C++ 2005 for Crystal reports, Visual studio Tools for Office 2010 , Visual C++ 2010 redistributable and finally .NET framework.

Is there a way through which I don't need to deploy these prerequisites, inturn saving time and space?

May be there is a way to extract and include only those parts within these prerequisites which are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With certain exceptions, MSFT generally doesn't support this.  Using high level languages, frameworks, APIs and such come with a cost.  You don't get all that for free... it has to be deployed.

That said, you can make choices to make it more manageable.  You can target .NET 3.0+ and eliminate Windows XP and the .NET Framework suddenly doesn't need to be distributed.

You can also choose not to redistribute them and instead have your installer simply error out and tell the user to go install it.

It's one of those  "it is what it is"  problems.

Comment: It is one of the things that really frustrates me so thought may be I am missing some easy way around. Apparently seems there is none. Thanks a lot

Comment: FWIW, take a look at the new deployment model of .NET core.  C/C++ runtime can be deployed privately or statically linked but that does introduce security concerns as Microsoft can't patch it.  You'd have to service it.  VSTO, possibly deployed privately but not really.   In certain situations it can be possible to ship a single MSI and keep it simple.  But generally this is the price to pay for component based coding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are merge modules for CR for VC++ 2005 that you can include in your MSI build, but that redist isn't huge anyway. I also believe you don't need to install Visual Studio Tools for Office 2010 either, you need the Visual Studio Tools for Office 2010 Runtime Redistributable, not the same thing. The VC++ 2010 redist isn't that huge either, but again there are merge modules you could include in your MSI. I also suspect that you don't need the entire NET Framework, just the Client Profile redist.

Comment: I thought the same especially for .NET framework, included client profile and application started giving null reference exceptions. On the VC++ 2005 part there is note informing that if u are using merge modules, u need to include VC ++. You may be right about VS for Office but still combined space occupied by prerequisites is more than the space occupied by my assembly

Comment: I'd avoid those merge modules.  They introduce upgrade problems due to the way they interact with the WinSxS as I recall.